# How to apply ngclass for a specific row in html table using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm using angular and I want to apply a css class to a specific row here's the code:

componentjs:

```
 flag=false;
 
 delete(){
  flag=true;
 }
```

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let app of pages ; let i = index" [id]="i"
              class="hvr-fade">
              <td class="row-mid">{{app.nom}</td>
              <td class="row-right">
                <button class="delete" title="delete" (click)="delete()">
                  <i [ngClass]="(flag==false  )?'fa fa-trash':'fa fa-spinner fa-spin'"   aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

my goal is to change the button icon from trash to spinner when I click on the button. this code it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an *ngIf instead of an ngClass might resolve your issue.

Have a look at the following example:
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-ngif-else-angular-applications

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to apply a css class with a condition at the same time

Answer (score 0):

The flag will not work as it is global and applies to all row of table. You can use row index based solution.

Component.js

```
currentRowNumber = 0;

delete(index){
   this.currentRowNumber = index;
}
```

Component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let app of pages ; let i = index" [id]="i"
          class="hvr-fade">
          <td class="row-mid">{{app.no}}</td>
          <td class="row-right">
            <button class="delete" title="delete" (click)="delete(i + 1)">
              <i [ngClass]="(currentRowNumber != (i + 1))?'fa fa-trash':'fa fa-spinner fa-spin'"   aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but please edit you answer putting currentRowNumber !== (i + 1) instead